# Не подключаются настройки стилей

Tags: css, sass, scss

Есть файл `scss(style.scss)` в который импортируются другие файлы `scss(к примеру login.scss)`. Я добавляю какой-то код  в `login.scss`, и компилирую `style.scss` в файл `style.css`. Этот файл я подключаю на страницу но настройки которые я добавил в `login.scss` не применяются(хотя скомпилировались и отображаются в файле `style.css`).
Компилирую в cmd от Ruby, поставил себе `sass --watch`: `sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css`.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Стили кэшируются браузером, сбросьте кэш - Ctrl + F5

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что браузер кэширует файлы стилей и скриптов.

Даже если вы обновите сами файлы, то они продолжат существовать в кэше, и изменений на странице не будет видно.

Для сброса кэша используйте `Ctrl + F5`.

Если вы хотите, что бы страницы также обновлялись у тех кто просмотрел вашу страницу ранее, просто добавьте в основном html файле в пути к скрипту номер версии, в данном примере 34. И каждый раз при изменении скрипта итерируйте версию.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?34" >
```

Либо

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?ver=34" >
```

Как это работает?

`style.css?34` это уже не `style.css` и в кэше будет иметь отдельный элемент, таким образом итерируя номер версии мы создаём новый элемент в кэше. А то что идёт после `?` будет проигнорировано, и загрузится именно `style.css`, так как это название файла, а остальная часть это передаваемые параметры при обычных настройках веб сервера.